# Given this time series, what statistical methods would be used for description and forecasting?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, finance

These static cumulative default rate tables and charts come from [this public report](http://www.fitchratings.com.ar/uploads/kcri0908.pdf)  published by a credit rating agency.

Basically, you take all the loans originated in a period of time (a "vintage") and track the cumulative amount of money due but not repayed by the borrowers as a percentage of the amount of money lent (the "cumulative default rate") for each period of time.

Each curve in the chart (each vintage) shows the behaviour of *all* the credits given by the bank during a given period of time (say, a month or a quarter). This mean:

- Observations included in all the curves are originated by the same bank using the same rules, therefore they share common characteristics and similar behaviour.
- The dataset analyzed includes all the loans originated by the bank. The observations include the whole population, they do not come from a sampling process.

Some visualization:

**The dataset**

```
Vintages Amount 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 
1Q01 612,000 0.10 0.57 1.13 1.89 2.74 3.34 3.61 4.06 4.36 4.66 4.73 4.83 5.08 5.18 5.27 5.38 5.39 5.41 5.43 5.48 5.58 
2Q01 700,000 0.09 0.64 0.99 1.77 2.58 3.03 3.46 3.64 4.01 4.28 4.32 4.47 4.73 4.82 4.97 5.05 5.07 5.10 5.23 5.32 
3Q01 732,490 0.13 0.70 1.53 2.08 2.60 3.08 3.28 3.75 3.82 4.32 4.37 4.57 4.70 4.92 4.98 4.99 5.07 5.12 5.14 
4Q01 793,984 0.23 0.85 1.73 2.19 2.72 3.31 3.79 3.96 4.40 4.66 4.78 4.92 5.13 5.21 5.37 5.38 5.49 5.57 
1Q02 834,563 0.22 0.73 1.28 1.89 2.77 3.11 3.45 3.82 3.91 4.37 4.45 4.63 4.85 5.08 5.11 5.15 5.16 
2Q02 904,485 0.14 0.65 1.45 2.17 2.72 3.20 3.81 4.08 4.38 4.43 4.54 4.91 5.08 5.11 5.15 5.18 
3Q02 953,534 0.10 0.71 1.42 1.98 2.55 3.14 3.71 4.15 4.42 4.67 4.73 4.89 4.95 5.03 5.24 
4Q02 980,124 0.13 0.64 1.13 1.61 1.98 2.23 2.71 3.03 3.30 3.68 3.77 3.82 3.87 4.08 
1Q03 1,202,324 0.18 0.69 1.14 1.95 2.42 2.56 2.98 3.15 3.67 3.68 3.76 4.00 4.10 
2Q03 1,014,485 0.16 0.59 1.39 1.90 2.23 2.58 2.92 3.46 3.68 3.74 3.87 3.99 
3Q03 1,171,731 0.15 0.60 1.18 1.66 1.97 2.45 3.11 3.15 3.41 3.50 3.81 
4Q03 1,312,338 0.13 0.61 1.13 1.44 2.11 2.33 2.85 2.87 3.01 3.05 
1Q04 1,509,189 0.16 0.59 1.14 1.45 1.75 1.99 2.36 2.47 2.63 
2Q04 1,569,557 0.13 0.58 1.09 1.46 1.85 2.19 2.28 2.44 
3Q04 1,545,922 0.14 0.58 0.99 1.39 1.72 1.97 2.18 
4Q04 1,514,485 0.18 0.63 0.94 1.46 1.81 1.84 
1Q05 1,574,685 0.16 0.55 1.04 1.45 1.72 
2Q05 1,578,485 0.10 0.38 0.74 0.90 
3Q05 1,501,234 0.06 0.44 0.64 
4Q05 1,472,187 0.07 0.41 
1Q06 1,459,861 0.08
```

[image]

**The chart**
[image]

**For better visualization, I add a chart from another dataset with more observations.**
[image]

Since I'm not an expert in statistics, I'd like to know what kind of statistical methods I should study to be able to a) describe the behaviour of each vintage (for example, indicators to compare new credits versus old credits), and b) forecast the final cumulative default rate (the default rate at the end of the life of the credits) for the youngest vintages.

I know the I've only included very little information about the case, but I'm willing to do my research on any statistical method you would suggest as possibly useful.

Comment: I think question is more appropriate for the Quantitative Finance StackExchange forum rather than this one.

Comment: @rocinante I'll wait and see if somebody has any suggestion about this, otherwise I'll try again on quantitative finance. Ty!

Comment: Fair enough. For what it's worth, question (a) and question (b) are two entirely different things and can't really be summarized in an answer because entire books are written on the subject. You don't need statistical methods as much as you need a book on credit instruments. If you have not done so already, get some books on credit instruments. The Frank Fabozzi series and the Wiley Finance series are pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

This 'triangular' data structure (where a new 'diagonal' can be observed each time period) occurs in many contexts.

Some examples

- Age-period-cohort data is of this form. A few links:

A report by Bendix Carstensen is probably a decent place to read about these models:

http://publichealth.ku.dk/sections/biostatistics/reports/2006/ResearchReport06-1.pdf/

He has a 2007 paper as well. I'll try to  find the reference.

This article in the Stata Journal is worth a look too:

http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=st0211

Kupper, Janis, Karmous, & Greenberg (1985),
Statistical age-period-cohort analysis: a review and critique.
*J Chronic Dis.* 1985;38(10):811-30.
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/4044767

- Davison and Hinkley (1997) analyze the AIDS reporting data set from De Angelis and Gilks (1994), which is count data of this general form.

De Angelis, D. and Gilks, W.R. (1994) Estimating acquired immune deficiency syndrome accounting for reporting delay. *Journal of the Royal Statistical Society, A*, 157, 31–40.

Davison, A.C. and Hinkley, D.V. (1997) *Bootstrap Methods and Their Application*. Cambridge University Press.

- Claims- (Loss-) reserving data is of this form; there are many articles on the various kinds of analysis used for this data (though I regard many of the more popular approaches as badly misguided for several reasons)

The tendency to cumulate the data is common in this application; unfortunately the consequences of the particular kinds of dependence this induces are often ignored, and the impact this has on the ability to identify calendar-period changes is also often ignored.

- Bond yield curve data is of similar form

(there are numerous other kinds of data that come in this form or an equivalent form.)

---

I suggest you be cautious when analyzing the cumulated data - it induces dependence along the vintages and obscures potential calendar-period effects that may be very important; on the other hand, if analyzed as a proportion of the origination amount, the variance structure may require you to deal with it as cumulative.

One possibility is taking it back to the per-period data as dollar amounts with origination amount as exposure.

> they do not come from a sampling process.

This is a common issue, especially, with time series data - but you can regard it as a sample path from a process about which you wish to make inference.  The data can be seen as resulting from a probabilistic process which (if the history were re-run) would have turned out differently.

Comment: Sorry, but none of this really answers the questions posed, namely: (1) descriptive statistics for loans and (2) prediction for which loans perform better for the financial institution. Moreover it introduces biostats methods for which there is little to no ground for justifying why it would apply to a finance problem.

Comment: @rocinante It begins by discussing the *particular structure* of the data, which many people are not especially familiar with, relating it to problems which they may have heard of. Such a structure presents particular issues in the analysis which are common to *all* of those areas (such as, for example, the fact that there are three 'time' directions, but such that any two of them determine the third). This has been (to my mind) most clearly elucidated in the age-period-cohort framework but it applies to all the application areas I listed. ...(ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... *ANY* attempt to model or even describe these data needs to (explicitly or implicitly) be aware of, and preferably take this structure into account; failure to do so can lead to difficulties which are already well understood and have some good approaches to solutions. Your argument would be like claiming that a bank can't use a Poisson process to model the number of loan defaults because *biostatisticians* use it. I've made no particular attempt to introduce any particular methods yet, but any of the areas I have raised do use methods that may be relevant ... (ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... to the analysis of this data; to exclude ideas from consideration because the application area is different would be ludicrous. As for the charge that it's not a complete answer to the question -- indeed it isn't (yet).

Comment: That's not what I said at all, and you know that. None of your comment addresses *specifically* what the OP asked. Moreover, the repeated editing of your comment to alter your answer seems to me to be a tad against StackExchange forum rules. And that's all I'm going to comment on the matter.

Comment: @rocinante "*the repeated editing of your comment to alter your answer* ... *against forum rules*". Uh... you get a few minutes to edit for a good reason. If me editing my comments to clarify my intent bothers you, perhaps you can hold off responding until those (very) few minutes elapse, and respond at the end of that time. It's not like I'm throwing insults and then deleting it or something. If you can point to a rule that is broken by editing a comment, I'd love to read it.

Comment: answer =/= comment. Answers can be edited indefinitely.

Comment: @rocinante I'm responding to this: "*the repeated editing of your comment*". What did you mean if not my comment? If you mean my answers, they're able to be edited for good reason, too.

Comment: @rocinante as my answer currently stands, it's intended as a partial response to "*I'd like to know what kind of statistical methods I should study*", to which I so far give some pointers. I think it *does* respond to that part of the question even though it's not a complete answer to the entire question.

Comment: Since I'm new in stack exchange, I can't tell if rules are being broken or not. I'll have to skip that discussion. Still, the answer presents for first time a model that *could* fit this data structure. I have only taken a very quick look at part of the material suggested by glen_b. Since it's a new framework for me, I can't tell for sure if this is what I need or not, but data visualization in the articles is kind of similar to mine.

Comment: I have still to understand what's the third variable in the age-period-cohort framework. Period should be the period of time in which the measurements has taken place (each moment during the life of the subject observed, the horizontal axis of the chart I posted in the question). Either age or cohort could be the "vintage", the group of assets originated during the same period of time. I still fail to see the difference between age and cohort, but I assume this will become clear after reading the material recommended.

Comment: Apart from that, I find it interesting that cumulative data is mentioned to be flawed. Unfortunately, this is common practice in the financial industry and I'm positive that periodical data allows better visualization of the calendar period. Indeed, credits originated during certain months of the year are clearly more risky (higher default rate) than those originated during other periods of the year. However, I assume that I can still see these effects in the cumulative data: periodical data is the difference between the cumulative data at two given points of time.

Comment: _One possibility is taking it back to the per-period data as dollar amounts with origination amount as exposure._ What's the difference in working with dollar amounts? Would I use other statistical framework for doing so or would I still use an age-period-cohort model?

Comment: One issue is that it simply removes the upper bound, though that's probably not a pressing issue. A second issue is that it may make any economic inflation or other calendar year effects easier to identify. In your data this may not matter so much, but the possibility is worth keeping in mind.